# Format strings in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there anything like formatting a `string` to the format specified?

Eg:

If the string value is

```
"05/05/2013 05:06:23"
```

If the formatting type is

```
"d"
```

So if we pass both the values, the output should be

```
05/05/2013
```

I tried like using the function `Format("stirng value","format")`, but this gave me the `format` as o/p.

**Note**: The function should work for all the `datatypes`.

Comment: No, there is nothing that will magically work for all data types. Perhaps you can tell us what data types you actually need this for?

Comment: DateTime,Currency,decimals

Comment: That's not _all_ data types then, is it? Can you please clarify what the expected inputs and outputs of such a function should be like? It is really unclear from a single, date-ish example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to parse it into a `DateTime` object and then use the `ToString` again with your specified format.

```
Dim str = "05/05/2013 05:06:23"
Dim ci = new CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim formattedDate = DateTime.Parse(str).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", ci) // Returns 05/05/2013"
```

And no, there is no such thing which works for all data types.

If you want to convert another data type ( `Decimal` for example ), first convert your string into the respective type (`Decimal.Parse` ..etc) and then use ToString again for the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function like this ..

This function can accept any type and return any type (only tested on int and date)

```
Function ChangeThis(ByVal var As Object, ByVal Type As String) As Object
    If Not var.GetType.IsValueType() Then Return Nothing
    Select Case var.GetType().ToString
        Case "System.Int32" : MsgBox("Integer 32")
        Case "System.DateTime"
            If Type = "d" Then Return Convert.ToDateTime(var).Date
    End Select
    Return ""
End Function
```

You can test it

```
Dim s As Date = ChangeThis(Now(), "d")
MsgBox(s)
```

This is not too good, but it can help ..

Answer (score 1):

The VB.NET `Format` function will give you what you want; you just have to [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format.aspx) to ensure you supply known formats:

```
> (Strings:Format "12-03-04 5:01:23.456" "d")
d
> (Strings:Format "12-03-04 5:01:23.456" "Short Date")
12/03/2004
> (Strings:Format "12-03-04 5:01:23.456" "Long Date")
Friday, 12 March 2004
> (Strings:Format "50123.456" "Currency")
$50,123.46
>
```

<sub>The above is actually DotLisp and its output, but it is just calling `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For that to work you have to parse the string to datetime first, and then you can use:

```
myDateVariable.ToString("d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [the .net string.format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) function.  Howver, the format string needs to specify exactly what output you want.  Just using "format" as the format string will output "format", as you've already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Convert.ToDateTime("05/05/2013 05:06:23").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this.

```
 Dim strRawdate As String = "05/05/2013 05:06:23"
 Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strRawdate, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
 Dim reformatDate As String = dt.ToString("M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```